# insert div after a div based on value in field minus size of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of number fields with the class product-quantity. When I add a number to the input field a div class name-number-field should appear after the class name-number-header. When a number is taken away from the field, the last name-number-field should be removed.

when val= 8 and size= 0 8 div's should be added
when val= 8 and size= 3 5 div's should be added

this what I came up with, but I am stuck

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.product-quantity').on('change',function(){
    selector = "#product-"+$(this).attr('data-product-id')+
    "[data-size-field='"+$(this).attr('data-size') +"']";
if ($(this).val > $(selector).size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < (val-size); i++){
        $('.size-field').insertAfter($(".name-number-header"));
    }
}
if ($(this).val < $(selector).size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < (size-val); i++){
        $('.size-field :last').remove();
    }
}
});
});
```

http://s24.postimg.org/x4njd7r44/Screen_Shot_2013_12_12_at_6_03_47_PM.jpg

here is a link to a screen shot of the html inspection ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

html:

```
 <div class="size-column">

 <div class="size-field">
    <div id="size-label"></div>
    <div class="number-input">
        <input id="XSmall" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="XSmall" min="0" 
 max="9999" data-size="XSmall" data-product-id="1"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-field">
    <div id="size-label"></div>
    <div class="number-input">
        <input id="Small" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Small" min="0" 
 max="9999" data-size="Small" data-product-id="1"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-field">
    <div id="size-label"></div>
    <div class="number-input">
        <input id="Medium" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Medium" min="0" 
 max="9999" data-size="Medium" data-product-id="1"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

....up to 5xl

```
<div class="name-number-form" data-switch="1" style="display: none;">

<div class="name-number-header"></div>
<div id="number-field-set">
    <div class="name-number-field" data-size="XSmall">
    </div>
    <div class="name-number-field" data-size="Small">
    </div>
    <div class="name-number-field" data-size="Medium">
    </div>
```

...up to 5xl

Edited code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.product-quantity').on('change',function(){
selector = "#product-"+$(this).attr('data-product-id')+
" [data-size-field='"+$(this).attr('data-size') +"']";
var val = $(this).val();
var size =  $(selector).size();
if (val > size) {
for (var i = 0; i < (val-size); i++){
    $('hi').insertAfter($(".name-number-header"));
}
}
if (val < size) {
for (var i = 0; i < (size-val); i++){
    $('.name-number-field :last').remove();
}
}
});
```

});

I created a fiddle that simulates something like what I am trying to do. What I dont want is the second input to effect the adding and removing of the div in the first column.

http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/19/

Comment: Showing some of your basic HTML would be very helpful...

Comment: I added a link to a screen shot of the html inspection. the code I wrote is in ruby. I can provided that too if that is more helpful

Comment: Can you add the html instead of a screenshot?

Comment: First of all, I think you have  a problem with your "selector" var. If I reference your html screenshot and cumpute it out, your var "selector" equals something like: `selector = "#product-1[data-size-field='XSmall']"` which is not what you want I don't think.

Comment: that is what I want because those fields belong to the product 1 and attr data-size-field= xsmall. I have many of them and they need to be associated with the right attr

Comment: ok, cool, now next..  your first for loop..  `if ($(this).val > $(selector).size) {` Do you mean `if ($(this).val() > $(selector).size())` ?

Comment: ok, next.. in your other two for-loops..  you have `val-size` and `size-val`.  There var's are not declared anywhere.. No offense intended, but you're going to need to improve your basic syntax error debugging skills.  :)  Just trying to help.  :)

Comment: I know I am sorry. but in the new code I put in my question I did declare size and val with :     var val = $(this).val();
    var size =  $(selector).size();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43084/discussion-between-bryan-elliott-and-anmaree)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.size-field').insertAfter($(".name-number-header"));
```

searches for elements with the class `size-field`.

If i understood your question correctly you want to create new `size-field` divs and append them.
If so, try it like that:

```
$('<div/>',{'class':'size-field'}).insertAfter($(".name-number-header"));
```

This will create a new div with class `size-field` and adds it after `.name-number-header`.

Comment: even if I just do $('<p>hi</p>').insertAfter($(".name-number-header")); it wont add anything.

Comment: @anmaree Do you get any errors? I made a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cqr2L/

Comment: yes i am getting the error Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined . Your example is what I want, I am just confused because I have many sets of them and they need to be associated with each other which is why I have to find (this) attr (data-size) and what not

Comment: Ah yes, you are using `$(this).val` which should be `$(this).val()`. And then `val` which doesn't exist. I'd just do `var val = $(this).val()` and then use only val throughout.

Comment: ok I added those changed to my question above. It still doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @anmaree Well, another error i see is that you used `$(selector).size` which should either be `$(selector).size()` or `$(selector).length`.